# Not going into method

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm just learning iOS development but I have experience in C++ and I'm having an issue where my I call a method on an object but that object is not being called. Here is my code:

```
@implementation EXCoursesViewController{
    EXNetworkingController *_networkController;
}

-(instancetype)initWithStyle: (UITableViewStyle)style{

    self = [super initWithStyle: style];
    if(self){
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";

        [_networkController createSession];

        [self fetchFeed];
    }
    return self;
}
```

`[_networkController createSession]` doesn't seem to actually call the createSession method in the `EXNetowrkingController` I made. I'm not sure why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should probably post the code for your "`createSession`" method.  Unless it's a singleton, you haven't done an "`alloc`" or "`init`" on the object.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure why this is happening.

Most likely, it's because `_networkController` is nil. It's apparently an instance variable, but you haven't given it a value at the point in `-initWithStyle:` where you're trying to send it a message.

To fix the problem, just create an `EXNetworkingController` instance and assign it to your ivar before using:

```
_networkController = [[EXNetworkingController alloc] init]; // or use the correct initializer
[_networkController createSession];
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not doing the `alloc` and `init` for your `EXNetworkingController`. What i recommend is make your `createSession` method as public and call it. It can be called through the `EXNetworkingController` class name itself.

Do something like this:

```
+(void)createSession{
    //Your createSession code goes here
}
```

You just have to replace the minus(-) which is in front of the `-(void)createSession` method with plus(+)

Then in your `EXCoursesViewController` class inside the `initWithStyle` replace `[_networkController createSession];` with `[EXCoursesViewController createSession];`

And you no longer require to make an object of your `EXCoursesViewController`.
So you can remove `EXNetworkingController *_networkController;`

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you recommending switching from an instance method to a class method? They're not really interchangeable -- a class method can't access instance variables, for example.

Comment: @Caleb: Yes you are right. I should have explained that part. This can be used be only if there are no instance variables used insie that method. Thanks for the clarification. I will keep this in mind.